# Publish profile error

Tags: wordpress, azure

When I download publish profile, there is an error. In azure, app service.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. This may have been caused by an incorrect user name and/or password.

Error message 401.1: Logon credentials were not recognized. Make sure you are providing the correct user name and password. Otherwise, contact the Web server's administrator for help.